# Fetching UniqueID of iphone

Tags: ios

How to fetch the ECID of iPhone programmatically . I need any unique ID to identify the device (except UUID). Serial number and UDID are can not be extracted after iOS 6 . Please suggest a solution . Thanks in advance

Comment: The link suggests me about UUID but the UUID changes when i do factory reset , I want something unique like UDID when doesn't change . So i thought ECID would help and i am looking for how to extract it progamatically

Comment: @Michael Dautermann : Pls let me know how to get the ECID of a phone ... the reply in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978725/calling-amdevicecopyvalue-from-mobiledeviceframework-help-please/30481898?noredirect=1#comment49043367_30481898 isn't very satisfying ... Thanks in advance